# How to find a value with in method definition in netbeans?

Tags: java, netbeans, find

### Search an item with in Method

In net beans, i want to search for an item which should not search beyond method definition.

1. Generally i used to do this in eclipse by double clicking near the
   open brace and it will select the entire method.
2. if i select CTRL+F, then i can search for a item with in that
   particular method.
3. Similarly i want to do that in net beans, please help me.
4. I have tried double clicking the open brace inside a method, but it just highlights the start and end braces alone.

Comment: Nope, it wasn't working. First of all, i want to select the contents of method definition and search an item with in that boundary.

Answer (score 0):

I can get the behavior you request by first selecting the whole method. Instead of double-clicking the braces,

1. Place the marker near the first brace
2. Hold down shift while clicking the second.
3. Ctrl+F to bring up search window.

It will now only search in the selected block while the search window is open.

Comment: It is not working in netbeans as expected. If i do as aforesaid, it just highlights the braces.